# An event for when the last object is saved via Django formset

Tags: python, django, signals, formset

I have a signal that listens to a model whose relation to another model is like this

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=4)

class ChildToModel1(models.Model):
    model_1 = models.ForeinKey(Model1, related_name='model_1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now I have an `inlineformset_factory` for `ChildToModel1` according to django calling save for ChildToModel1 inlineformset_factory will save multiple instance of ChildToModel1 like it's a forloop. If I have, for example; 3 formset is there a way to check the total of the objects after total save and not on each save, I am accessing these on the model post_save signal.

printing `ChildToModel1` on post_save signal returns something like this

```
<QuerySet [obj]>
<QuerySet [obj][obj]>
<QuerySet [obj][obj][obj]>
```

What I really want is:

```
<QuerySet [obj][obj][obj]>
```

Comment: Why does this specifically need to be a signal anyway? Why can you not simply run your code after you save the form? Also even if this needs to be a signal for other apps to plug into it, you can create your own signal quite easily.

Comment: Because I'm comparing object already in the database with similar structure to the one being saved in the formset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger other signal manually at the end.

First define new signal: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/#defining-signals

```
import django.dispatch

post_save_after_last = django.dispatch.Signal()
```

and then import it and trigger it

```
from somewhere import post_save_after_last

last_instance = ChildToModel1(field='qwerty')
post_save_after_last.send(sender=ChildToModel1, instance=instance)
```

You can read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/#sending-signals